# How do I force new users to fill out their User: page when they create a new account on a MediaWiki wiki?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

The unnecessary new user mistakes I'm having to revert on the wiki are getting annoying.. Is there any way for me to preload their `User:Username` with instructions on finding any help they may need and links to places to ask questions, further-more, is there any way to require new users to make three `User:Username` / `User_talk:Username` / `User_talk:SomeAdmin` page edits before editing other pages?

Comment: In addition: I've see it added automatically when users' log in details are matched to the IT database - but I don't know to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have no power to install/remove extensions on this wiki, I had to go with what I have.  The wiki has [Extension:InputBox](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aInputBox) installed.. So, I set up [Template:Welcome](http://ddowiki.com/page/Template%3aWelcome), created a [preload](http://ddowiki.com/page/MediaWiki%3aWelcomecreation/preload), and set up [MediaWiki:Welcomecreation](http://ddowiki.com/page/MediaWiki%3aWelcomecreation) with a simple button that does most of the heavy lifting so to speak...  It does not actually force anything, but gives all of the needed information and has a similar final output to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to force it, but here is a trick I use:

1. Download and install the [MyVariables](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMyVariables) extension.
2. Create a template to use it called `{{User name}}` - code below.
3. Include this template in a welcome message on your main page. The user will then see either `Welcome <their name>` if they have filled it in or `Welcome enter your user name` if they have not.

Two points on this template:

- if they have not entered their name, the text links to a page explaining how to do that (you will need to create this),
- if they have entered their name, the text links to `MY PREFERENCES` where they can update their user data.

Of course, you can change this if that is overkill.

The code:

`{{#if:{{CURRENTUSERREALNAME}}|[[MY PREFERENCES|{{CURRENTUSERREALNAME}}]]|[[How to create your user profile on this wiki|enter your user name]]}}<noinclude>`

`<Add text here explaining the template, or just link to this stackoverflow page!>`

`[[Category:Template]]`

`</noinclude>`

Answer (score 1):

Another "trick" I've used is using the [NewUserMessage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNewUserMessage) extension to ask users to add this information.